# C programming for Robotics

Tags: c, robotics, webots

I have a robotic car in Webots simulation that needs to stop at a place whenever I press a key on keyboard. So if I press 1, it should stop at coordinate X = 140 and coordinate Z = 50. On this code, the speed goes up and down with UP and DOWN arrow. I may have to insert if statement under case 1 but don't know how to implement. The robot constantly runs on a line and should only stop or act when prompted with a keyboard command. The code given below is just a snippet, I can provide the full code if necessary. I'm a novice just starting a course on C.

```
// GPS
WbDeviceTag gps;
double gps_coords[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
double gps_speed = 0.0;

// misc variables
double speed = 0.0;
double steering_angle = 0.0;
int manual_steering = 0;
bool autodrive = true;

void print_help() {
  printf("You can drive this car!\n");
  printf("Select the 3D window and then use the cursor keys to:\n");
  printf("
/
- steer\n");
  printf("[UP]/[DOWN] - accelerate/slow down\n");
}

void set_autodrive(bool onoff) {
  if (autodrive == onoff)
    return;
  autodrive = onoff;
  switch (autodrive) {
    case false:
      printf("switching to manual drive...\n");
      printf("hit [A] to return to auto-drive.\n");
      break;
    case true:
      if (has_camera)
        printf("switching to auto-drive...\n");
      else
        printf("impossible to switch auto-drive on without camera...\n");
      break;
  }
}


void check_keyboard() {
  int key = wb_keyboard_get_key();
  switch (key) {
    case WB_KEYBOARD_UP:
      set_speed(speed + 5.0);
      break;
    case WB_KEYBOARD_DOWN:
      set_speed(speed - 5.0);
      break;
    case WB_KEYBOARD_RIGHT:
      change_manual_steer_angle(+1);
      break;
    case WB_KEYBOARD_LEFT:
      change_manual_steer_angle(-1);
      break;
    case 'A':
      set_autodrive(true);
      break;
    case '1':
      if (gps_coords[X] == "104.9" && gps_coords[Z] == "48.9") {
      set_speed(speed - speed);
  }
     break;
}
```

Comment: You can't put `if (gps_coords[X] == "104.9" && gps_coords[Z] == "48.9") { set_speed(speed - speed); }` inside the keyboard handler because it will only check that wen you press the number.  You need to have the keyboard handler set a flag and then in your main do `if (one_pressed == true && gps_coords[X] == "104.9" && gps_coords[Z] == "48.9") { set_speed(speed - speed); }`

Comment: As @JerryJeremiah said - but even doing that will only stop if the car has EXACTLY those values of 104.9, 48.9.  If there is even the tiniest amount of difference (eg, the car is at 104.8999999, 48.90000001) then the car will not stop  (and note that 140,50 is WAY more different ).  Also, I notice that `gps_coords` is declared as a `double` array - so why are you comparing them to `char *` strings ?   Also, your question refers to 140, but your code has 104.9 - why ?